# How to move two different CCSprites independently at the same time?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I am new with programming games with cocos2d.  I went through the following tutorial on how to move two different CCSprites:

http://www.qcmat.com/dragging-multiple-sprites-in-cocos2d/

The tutorial subclasses CCSprite with Targeted Touch Delegate, but it only lets one CCSprite to move at one time.  I was wondering how I could move two different CCSprites at the same time but in different directions.  For example: one thumb on a CCSprite moving it to the left and another thumb moving another CCSprite to the right, both being done at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the GL View set the MultipleTouchEnabled to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

For your touch implementation, check out the example of snekyjoystick for cocos2d. 
link,  http://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyJoystick  . I did same kind of implementation in previous project and it works fine ! Code wont help you to use directly, you have to find it out from it.. Best luck !